# SocketTimeout: Read timed out

Tags: apache-flex, iis

I'm using Flex - IIS - ASP.NET to do remote calls. When I stresstest, all remote calls that take longer than 30 seconds fail. In Charles I get a message saying 'SocketTimeout: Read timed out'.  Is this something that can be configured in IIS? Or could it be a problem with a setting in Charles?

Answer (score 1):

No clue what Charles is....

...but you know that ASP.NET has a script timeout limit that is 30 seconds per default (but you can change it, even in code in the page)?

Comment: I'm gonna try to set this in the web.config.

Comment: So what IS charles? Can it be you get a timeout from the OTHER side (the service you call)?

Comment: Charles is a http monitor written in Java, so I guess the problem could be there.

Comment: Possibly. Looks like something on the way times out.